# Query optimization [Oracle DBMS]

Tags: oracle, performance, query-performance, optimization, oracle-11g

I have a query that always must return a single row and its execution time is about 5s, so I need to optimize it:

```
SELECT * FROM RESPONSE res
INNER JOIN REQUEST req ON res.ID = req.ID
WHERE res.FIELD_47 = ? 
AND req.CREATE_DATE = ( SELECT max(req2.CREATE_DATE) FROM RESPONSE r2
INNER JOIN REQUEST req2 ON r2.ID = req2.ID
WHERE r2.FIELD_47 = ? );
```

All present columns have a index and my db is transactional. Please suggest me.
Thank you!

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT 
   MAX(req.CREATE_DATE) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY req.CREATE_DATE DESC) CREATE_DATE,
   MAX(req.column_x) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY req.CREATE_DATE DESC) column_x,
   MAX(req.column_y) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY req.CREATE_DATE DESC) column_y,
   ... some more columns, same as above
FROM RESPONSE res
    INNER JOIN REQUEST req ON res.ID = req.ID
WHERE res.FIELD_47 = ?;
```

Comment: Thank you for response, but I don't think I can implement it with hibernate, I just posted the question again focused on Hibernate, from and thank you very much.